# Can "main" in java return a String?

Tags: java, string, return, program-entry-point

Is it possible that public static void main(String[] args) in java returns `String` instead of `void`? If yes, how?

```
public static String main(String[] args)
```

instead of:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

when I change my code as below:

```
public static String main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String str = null;
    TurkishMorphParser parser = TurkishMorphParser.createWithDefaults();
    str = new Stm(parser).parse("bizler");
    System.out.println("str = " + str);
    String replace = str.replace("[","");
    String replace1 = replace.replace("]","");
    List<String> result1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(replace1.split(",")));
    String result = result1.get(0);
    System.out.println("Result = " + result);
    return result;        
}
```

I receive this error:

```
Error: Main method must return a value of type void in class Stm, please define the main method as:
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Not possible with same method arguments. Method overloading is defined by argument type and count not by return type.

Comment: The exception is telling you can't, so no you can't.

Comment: Ask yourself, what would it return it *to*, and what would the thing it was returned to be expected to do with it?

Comment: system.exit("") - is on of the way - better explained here   
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130264/can-a-main-method-in-java-return-something

Answer (score 7):

In short - no, it can't.
You can always print to stdout from the main method (using `System.out.print` or `System.out.println`), but you can't change the return type of `main`.

Answer (score 5):

The main method's return type must be `void`, because the java language specification enforces it. See [12.1.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4).

For interprocess communication you can either use:

- `System.in` and `System.out`
- Sockets

Answer (score 2):

No you can't... once the main is finished the program is dead.. So you don't have any benefit from that.. What is you purpose? What you are trying to achieve?

You can wrap all in other method that will return String to your main.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   String result = doSomething();
return result;


}
public static String doSomething() {
   String str = null;
   TurkishMorphParser parser = TurkishMorphParser.createWithDefaults();
   str = new Stm(parser).parse("bizler");
   System.out.println("str = " + str);
   String replace = str.replace("[","");
   String replace1 = replace.replace("]","");
   List<String> result1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(replace1.split(",")));
   String result = result1.get(0);
   System.out.println("Result = " + result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can but you can't run that class. You will get error

```
class Test {

        public static String main(String[] args) {
                return "1";
        }
}
```

You will get error as

```
Error: Main method must return a value of type void in class Test, please 
define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
```

Comment: A bit incorrect. You cannot run the class using the usual way. But you can write a custom loader that executes the modified main.

Answer (score 2):

No. The to be a `main()` method, it must return nothing (ie be `void`).

However, you could refactor your code if you need the functionality of your method returning something:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    myMain(args);
}

public static String myMain(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // your method, which can now be called from anywhere in your code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a very interesting scenario. While in general, we can change any method which is returning void to return anything else without much impact, main method is a special case.

In earlier programming languages, the return from main method was supposed to return exit values to the OS or calling environment.

But in case of Java (where multi-threading concept case into picture), returning a value from main method would not be right, as the main method returns to JVM instead of OS. JVM then finishes other threads e.g. deamon threads (if any) and performs other exit tasks before exit to OS.

Hence allowing main method to return, would have lead to a false expectation with the developers. hence it is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's definitely possible. That is, you can define a method `public static String main(String[] args)`. It's just like defining any other method.

However, **it won't be a main method** despite its name, and thus won't be run when executing a program like a main method would. Quoting Java language specification, §12.14:

> The method main must be declared public, static, and **void**.

Emphasis mine. You can't have non-void main methods in Java.

Comment: The declarations would have the same signature if run in the same class.

Comment: @Makoto, I don't see how that relates to this.

Comment: It would.  If you declared `public static void main(String[] args)` and `public static String main(String[] args)`, that wouldn't compile since both methods would have the same signature.  It's not a complete answer until it addresses that point.

Comment: @Makoto, yes, but I don't see there being a question about having both versions of `main` in the same class. Only about whether `main` can return a `String` instead of `void`, which I already answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you really, really need it to return something (which you don't), assign the output to a static variable. Then you won't need to return. i.e

```
static String a = "";
public static void main(String[] args){
     //do sth
     a = "whatever you want";
}
```

Now you have `String a`, use it whereever you want to use but I don't see any usage for this.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is no.

When the program is run, the JVM looks for a method named main() which takes an array of Strings as input and **returns nothing (i.e. the return type is void)**. But if it doesn't find such a method ( **the main() method is returning String** for example ) so it throws a **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError**

Answer (score 0):

Before java, in C or C++, main function could be declared int or void. Why? Because main method is invoked by OS which is not responsible for the successful/unsuccessful execution of program. So, to let the OS know that the program executed successfully we provide a return value.

Now, in java, program is loaded by OS, but the execution is done by JRE. JRE itself is responsible for the successful execution of program. So, no need to change the return type.

It will be like telling your problems to god, when god himself is giving you problems to solve them.

;)