# Can't find main class in Java?

Tags: java

For some reason that I haven't been able to figure out, the program I've been working on for a while now isn't running. This is the error message I've been getting:
[image]

All I did between the time it was working and now was add another class, but even after deleting it the error message is still here. Netbeans has also been unhelpful, there aren't any errors marked in red in the code. I'm still a beginner to Java, so I don't know how much is needed to find the error, so here is all of the code:

```
public class ChooseYourOwn {
static class Character {
    private static int str;
    public Character() {
        int str = 0;
        int spd = 0;
        int agl = 0;
        int def = 0;
        int mag = 0;
        int wil = 0;
        int mp = 0;
        int hp = 0;
    }
    private Character(String name) {
    }
    }

/**
 *
 * @param args
 * @return
 */

public static int main(String[] args) {
    //set up character
    System.out.println("Choose a class:");
    String [] genusOptions;
    genusOptions = new String[] {"\n1-Warrior\n2-Mage\n3-Thief"};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(genusOptions));
    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String genus;
    genus = input1.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Your character's stats are:");
    switch (genus) {
        case "1":
            {
                String[] array = new String[] {"\nStrength-15\nSpeed-5\nAgility-5\nDefense-10\nMagicDamage-5\nMagicDefense-0\nMagicPoints-5\nHitPoints-15\n"};
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
                int str = 5; 
                int spd = 2;
                int agl = 2;
                int def = 5;
                int mag = 0;
                int wil = 0;
                int mp = 0; 
                int hp = 10;
                break;
            }
        case "2":
            {
                String[] array = new String[] {"\nStrength-5\nSpeed-5\nAgility-5\nDefense-0\nMagicDamage-15\nMagicDefense-10\nMagicPoints-15\nHitPoints-5\n"};
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
                int str = 5; 
                int spd = 5;
                int agl = 5;
                int def = 0;
                int mag = 10;
                int wil = 10;
                int mp = 15; 
                int hp = 5;
                break;
            }
        case "3":
            {
                String[] array = new String[] {"\nStrength-10\nSpeed-15\nAgility-15\nDefense-10\nMagicDamage-10\nMagicDefense-5\nMagicPoints-10\nHitPoints-10\n"};
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
                int str = 10; 
                int spd = 15;
                int agl = 15;
                int def = 10;
                int mag = 10;
                int wil = 5;
                int mp = 10;
                int hp = 10;
                break;
            }
    }
    String[] array = new String[] {"\n1-Move\n2-Rest\n3-Attack\n4-Run\n5-Activate lever/button/chest\n6-Inventory\n7-Skills"};
    System.out.println("Choose a number to continue");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    Scanner input2;
    input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String action;
    action = input2.nextLine();
    switch (action) {
        case "1":
            {
                System.out.println("");
                //not done yet
                break;
            }
        case "2":
            {
                System.out.println("");
                //Rest, restores some health
                break;
            }
        case "3":
            {
                System.out.println("");
                int max = 100;
                int min = 0;
                Random rand = new Random();
                int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
                int damage = 0;
                if (10 > randomNum) {
                    damage = (Character.str/100) * 10;
                } else if (20 > randomNum) {
                    damage = (Character.str/100) * 20;
                } else if (30 > randomNum) {
                    damage = (Character.str/100) * 30;
                } else if (40 > randomNum) {
                    damage = (Character.str/100) * 40;
                } else if (50 > randomNum) {
                    damage = (Character.str/100) * 50;
                } else if (60 > randomNum) {
                    damage = (Character.str/100) * 60;
                } else if (70 > randomNum) {
                    damage = (Character.str/100) * 70;
                } else if (80 > randomNum) {
                    damage = (Character.str/100) * 80;
                } else if (90 > randomNum) {
                    damage = (Character.str/100) * 90;
                } else if (100 > randomNum) {
                    damage = Character.str;
                }
                System.out.println( damage );
                break;
                }
        case "4":
            {
                System.out.println("");
                //not done yet
                break;
            }
        case "5":
            {
                System.out.println("");
                //not done yet
                break;
            }
        case "6":
            {
                System.out.println("");
                //not done yet
                break;
            }
        case "7":
            {
                System.out.println("");
                //not done yet
            }       
    }
    return (0);
}
}
```

There have been similar questions asked here before, but none of them helped and others were very unclear. A good and coherent answer would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, the main method signature is **`public static void main(String[] args)`**, however in your code you are using `public static int main(String[] args)`.

Answer (score 2):

Java main methods are declared like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
...
}
```

More information can be found at [Can a main method in Java return something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130264/can-a-main-method-in-java-return-something)

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the return type of `main`. This,

```
public static int main(String[] args)
```

must be one of (per this worthwhile [Wikipedia article on `Entry point`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point#Java))

```
public static void main(String[] args)
public static void main(String... args)
public static void main(String args[])
```

All of which are `void`, if you need to set a `UNIX` style return type, you can use [`System.exit(int);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29) to quote the Javadoc that

> Terminates the currently running Java Virtual Machine. The argument serves as a status code; by convention, a nonzero status code indicates abnormal termination.