# it throws me error incompatible types: unexpected return value -- return 10; please correct it make note where i am doing wrong code?

Tags: java

//return rule break

```
class Fianalblck
{

    public static void main(String... s)
    {
        //int show

        int x;
        {
            try {
                return 10;
            }
            catch(Exception e)   {

            }
            finally {
                return 20;
            }
        } System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: `void` doesn't `return` a value...(oh and `x`'s value is undefined, which will cause another error)

Comment: You definitely have some problems in your code. I was going to edit it but it is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Your main method is `void` meaning it can't return anything. If you wish to return a value, create another method that is a returnable type (`boolean, int, double, String,` etc.) then call that method from your main.

It looks like you need to start from the beginning, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/) is a link to a java basics tutorial.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) is a tutorial on `return`.

Answer (score 1):

void means the method cannot return any value. if you wish to quit the application with exit code you can use System.exit().

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.exit(10);
}
```

refer [Can a main method in Java return something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130264/can-a-main-method-in-java-return-something)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want to do:

```
class Fianalblck
{
    private int func() {
        try {
            return 10;
        }
        catch(Exception e)   {

        }
        finally {
            return 20;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String... s)
    {
        Fianalblck f = new Fianalblck();
        int x;
        x = f.func();
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

You want to try whether 10 or 20 will be returned from a method.

In java, you have to declare a new method, and call that method with the instance of Fianalblck.

Comment: thanx iyen i was trying to know that is there any way so that i can get return value without using any function or only by main.

Answer (score 0):

Main method **cannot return a value** directly.

```
 Error: Main method must return a value of type void in class first, please
 define the main method as:
 public static void main(String[] args)
```

But you can simply use **return** in a main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
...
...
...
return;
}
```